# What do these npm warnings mean when installing Jest in Linux?

Tags: node.js, npm, warnings

While installing Jest with npm I received the following warnings. I would like to know in general what they mean:

```
npm install --save-dev jest
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/burtrandpaulie/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^2.1.2 (node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/burtrandpaulie/package.json'
npm WARN burtrandpaulie No description
npm WARN burtrandpaulie No repository field.
npm WARN burtrandpaulie No README data
npm WARN burtrandpaulie No license field.

+ jest@26.6.3
added 520 packages from 355 contributors and audited 521 packages in 61.729s

24 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Answer (score 0):

All the ones prior to the last 4 are related to dependencies of jest.  There are some packages jest uses that have announced they are deprecating, but at this point they are still in wide use (e.g. `request`) so you can inquire with the jest project what their plan is, but while deprecated the `request` module will likely be around a while.

The last 4 lines are about your own package.json:

```
npm WARN burtrandpaulie No description
npm WARN burtrandpaulie No repository field.
npm WARN burtrandpaulie No README data
npm WARN burtrandpaulie No license field.
```

which just says your package.json doesn't have that info.  Nothing crazy or required esp. if you're just starting a project.